# billing address in checkout page out of select box

Tags: billing

I want to show the billing address in a `div` not in *select type box.*

In `billing.phtml`file

```
<div class="input-box">
    <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
</div>
```

This statement is creating select box and displaying the address.
Here is the code in `Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract.php`

```
public function getAddressesHtmlSelect($type)
{
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $address) {
            $options[] = array(
                'value' => $address->getId(),
                'label' => $address->format('oneline')

            );

        }
        $addressId = $this->getAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
        Mage::log($addressId,null,'address.log');
        if (empty($addressId)) {
            if ($type=='billing') {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            }
            if ($address) {
                $addressId = $address->getId();
            }
        }

        $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'_address_id')
            ->setId($type.'-address-select')
            ->setClass('address-select')
            ->setExtraParams('onchange="'.$type.'.newAddress(!this.value)"')
            ->setValue($addressId)
            ->setOptions($options);

        $select->addOption('', Mage::helper('checkout')->__('New Address'));

        return $select->getHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

This function is returning the address.

Answer (score 2):

There is no in build function to list the customer address as div

You have get the customer address by following code

use the below code after this

```
<?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
```

and hide the address select box (i.e., Display:none)

```
<?php $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();?>    
<?php $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId->getId()); ?>
<?php $data = array();?>

<?php foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address):?>
<?php $data = $address->toArray();?>
<div id="addresseList<?php echo $data['entity_id'];?>">
    <a href="javaScript:void(0);" onclick="setAdd(<?php echo $data['entity_id'];?>,this)" id="<?php echo $data['entity_id'];?>">
        <address>                         
            <?php echo '<p><b>'.$data['firstname'].' '.$data['lastname'].'</b></p>';?>
            <?php echo '<p>'.$data['street'].'</p>';?>
            <?php echo '<p>'.$data['city'].','.$data['region'].','.$data['postcode'].'</p>';?>
            <?php $country_name = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($data['country_id']);?>
            <?php echo '<p>'.$country_name.'</p>';?>
            <?php echo 'T: '.$data['telephone'];?>
        </address>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
 // new address button
<div class="actions text-center">
    <a href="javaScript:void(0);" onclick="setNewAddress()" class="btn"><?php echo $this->__('Add New');?></a>
</div>
```

then add the below `script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function setAdd(value)
{
    ​document.getElementById('billing-address-select').value = value;
    //jQuery("#billing-address-select").val(value);
}

function setNewAddress()
{ 
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);
}

//]]>
</script>
```